# How to write a power using `WriteString` function

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting, output

I have a solution of an equation:

```
aa = N[Rationalize[g6[[3, 2]], 0], 16]

(* Out: 2.691607147352649*10^-6 *)
```

I want to save this result in a file using `WriteString` function.

```
m = OpenAppend["/home/mateus/LaminarSeparationBubble/RD/Dados/02/teste.dat"];
WriteString[m, N[Rationalize[aa, 0], 16]]
Close["/home/mateus/LaminarSeparationBubble/RD/Dados/02/teste.dat"];
```

The output file is in this form:

```
                    -6
2.691607147352649 10
```

How to save correctly? Some like that:

```
2.691607147352649E-06
```

Comment: Try `CForm[aa]`